# How to disable jQuery click event on label?

Tags: jquery, html

Here is an example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/whitesiroi/9oxomwL2/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <label class="control-label" for="TopicWords">Label</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input type="text" id="TopicWords">
  </div>
</div>

<br/><br/>
<span id="message"></span>
```

JS:

```
$('.wrapper').on('click','input#TopicWords', function() {
  $('#message').fadeIn('fast').text('Clicked').fadeOut('slow');
})
```

Click event runs on both `input#TopicWords` or `label`. How to make it run only when `input#TopicWords` was clicked

Is there other way except than:

```
$(".control-label[for='TopicWords']").on('click', function() {
  return false;
});
```

Or shortcut:

```
$(".control-label[for='TopicWords']").on('click', false);
```

UPDATE:
Wrapper's content is dynamic, sometimes I don't have div with class controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand your problem correctly, the solution you've added is the way to go. The reason why the click event also fires when you click on the label is because of the for attribute on that label.

It says if you click me as a label I will put the focus on the input specified in the for attribute.

Besides the solution you gave. You can optionally remove the for attribute of that label but is that something you want?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. yes, you're right. Maybe, there is a way I can catch in my click event and don't run it if LABEL was clicked.

Comment: I need for attribute, CMS-like system generates it.

Comment: I've tested all suggested answers and they don't work. However yours does and it's a good/propper solution.

Comment: I tried them all too. I was hoping to catch it with 'event' as function(event) {event.target ... == 'label'}  but wasn't able too.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('#TopicWords').click(function() {
   $('#message').fadeIn('fast').text('Clicked').fadeOut('slow');
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Because I have dynamic content it won't work.

Comment: Then how do you get the id TopicWords?. Can you elaborate on how the content is being loaded?

Comment: I'm getting it via ajax.

Comment: That's it. Where you are getting the content add the code that I posted. For instance. If you are doing like $('.wrapper').html(content); Immediately after this put the code I have posted. It will hook your function every time it loads. If your content is dynamic your code will only work after it is rehooked everytime the content loads. It will never work in document ready.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I'm doing it repeatedly, I change the previous wrapper's content with a new one several times, so I have to use 'on' or 'live'

Comment: Can you share your code, I am still unsure as to how you are changing the wrapper's html.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using CMS, so code is scattered all around :)
+1 Thank you for you help

Answer (score 0):

Other solution can be to check if input element was clicked

```
$('.wrapper').on('click','input#TopicWords', function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName==='INPUT') {
    $('#message').fadeIn('fast').text('Clicked').fadeOut('slow');
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. In both cases It fires.

Comment: @RayonDabre, you are right, same Event for both clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Please add this js also:

```
$('.wrapper label').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I want to solve it by one already existing click event : $('.wrapper').on('click','input#TopicWords', function() {...}